# Algorithm - What is wrong with this Sieve of Erastothenes solution

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I thought I would create my own implementation of the Sieve algorithm to find prime numbers quicker. Surprisingly, this fails a number of tests.

Here's my algorithm in Ruby for determining if a number is a prime.

```
def prime?(n)
  primes = [2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17]
  primes.include?(n) || primes.none? { |p| n % p == 0 }
end
```

How the algorithm works is you take the first couple prime numbers, I took the first 8 to be safe. I would then weed out all the multiples of these prime numbers, as there is no way they could be primes.

Therefore all the other numbers must be prime

I'm shocked to find out my tests fail and I overlooked some numbers. How is this possible? I'm following the algorithm perfectly.

Comment: Any product of primes not in your finite list will be incorrectly categorised as prime by your function. For example, 19*19, or 19*23, or 19*29*37.

Comment: You are not following Seive of Erastothenes approach at all.

Comment: The answer is that you are not following the algorithm perfectly.  And that it is simply not true that once you've weeded out all multiples of the first 8 prime numbers, all other numbers are prime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants

Comment: @user5301625 : `Seive of Erastothenes` - is that you mocking the misspelled name, or a spelling checker in festive coma?

Comment: Are we being trolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test primality of a given number `n` you need to check whether it's divisible by any of the primes <= sqrt(`n`).  Since you have hardwired the primes up to 17 into it, your algorithm will only work for values of `n` <= 17<sup>2</sup>.

On top of that, you included 9 in your list of "primes".  This shouldn't affect your test except for the value 9 itself, since anything divisible by 9 is also divisible by 3, but it's quite naughty.

Comment: @CoderX I haven't posted any method, I've explained the limitations of his method.  What part of the explanation do you not understand?

Comment: Seive of Erastothenes approach is not limited by <= 17*17. It will just find next smallest number not striked out, and remove all the multiples of that number less than n.

Comment: @CoderX His implementation is limited by 17*17.  The biggest numbers he can test for primality are limited by the square of the largest prime he includes in his known set.

Comment: Yes. But he is claiming that he is using Seive of Erastothenes approach. But, he is not. So, he needs to change the approach.

Comment: @CoderX If you have a bone to pick about calling it sieve of Eratosthenes, your complaint is not with me.  Regardless, OP's algorithm will give correct answers about the primality of argument `n` for a limited range of `n` (after removing the 9).  His question was why his algorithm was sometimes giving wrong answers, I have explained why.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have included 9 in the list of primes. 9 is not a prime number.
Try following approach.

- To find all the primes up to a given number. Start with the smallest prime, 2.
- Mark 2 as prime, and strike out all the multiples of 2.
- Next see, which is the smallest number not striked out. It is 3. Print 3 as prime and strike out all the multiples of 3 smaller than n.
- Then again select the next smallest number not striked out, and so on

  ```
  def primeSeive(n)
      while primes[index]**2 <= primes.last
          prime = primes[index]
          primes = primes.select { |x| x == prime || x%prime != 0 }
          index += 1
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good at ruby but it seems you're not following the algorithm. 
Also you add 9 as prime number which is not true.

In **sieve algorithm** at first only need **2** as a prime number.

**Pseudocode**:

```
Sieve(n) {
  a[1] := 0                          
  for i := 2 to n do a[i] := 1
  p := 2
  while p2  <  n do {
    j := p2
    while (j  <  n) do {             
      a[j] := 0
      j := j+p
    }
    repeat p := p+1 until a[p] = 1   
  }
  return(a)
}
```

here *A* is the array,which's index value indicate the **primeness**.  **0** for *not prime*, **1** for *prime*.
in **while** loop mark prime numbers multiple and last pick next prime number in **repeat** section.